# iOS Autolayout - black screen when adding view above table view

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have UIViewController with UITableView which fill entire screen (I am using auto layout). When I add some view to the view above table view sometimes when I push to this view controller I see black screen, but only in the place where should be table view. Sometimes when I remove the view and add other then works sometimes not. So I have no idea why sometimes works sometimes not and what can cause thsi error. I can even add only IBOutlet to the one of the constraints and then I see black screen, if I then delete the view with this constraint, then works and if I then click undo and the view comes again, then works. I don't undernstand it.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was my error I didn't notice. I set view of my view controller to tablew view in the interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

The default tableview background colour is black so it may be that you're table isn't being populated. Try setting the bg colour of the table view to something obvious (e.g. red) and also check your datasource is available when the table is trying to layout.

Comment: I changed the background color, but I see always black screen. I think this is nothing wrong with table view, only with auto layout.

Comment: Perhaps you could share your constraints?

Comment: I think everything is ok when the views are neighbours, the problem is when I try to add a view above table view and the table view fill entire screen.

Comment: Are you explicitly setting constraints or letting Xcode handle it?

Comment: I added in IB constraints for table view to the all sides of the superview (using Add Missing Constraits).